# Sending screen to another monitor

Tags: linux, windows, remote-desktop, remote-control

In the movies they are able to put other peoples screen or content up on the big screen. Is there a way to do such activities in real world scenarios with an application?

I would like to be able to put say a browser up on a big screen from one of our many monitoring stations.

EDIT:
I guess a KVM is always an option. Wish could explain this better but **basically wondering if it would be possible to at any given point pick a window on one of many work stations and be able to display it up on a big screen.**

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to be able to monitor ALL workstations, and when you feel something is interesting on say Workstation A is good for public viewing, you (as the admin) can "grab" that screen, and display it on the big screen?

Comment: Yea, something like that. Just curious if that is at all possible.

Comment: Not sure about the big screen, but my workplace once trialled a software called [LanSchool](http://www.lanschool.com/lanschool/features/teach) that can 'grab' a student monitor, to be displayed to everyone's monitor (we didn't end up using it due to lack of man hour to do research on it for the workplace use). But since it has the ability to grab a monitor for displaying everywhere, I'm assuming that it may have the ability to grab a monitor to be displayed on the "admin" monitor, and the 'admin' monitor may have a 2nd monitor which is the big screen.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to accomplish this that you are unlikely to get a response unless you elaborate a little more on this…

What is your specific scenario?  You can use a computer setup to the tv with SSH and X forwarding/remote display/vnc/etc…  And there are devices that can send the video output over cat5/ethernet and through a VGA/DVI adapter.

Just *spitballin'* a solution [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WBMU3W)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is "Kiosk Mode", where your big screen is physically connected to the the video output of a dedicated PC and you just start IE to whatever monitor URL site you are interested in displaying.
 Starting IE in [kiosk mode is described here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780).

Answer (score 0):

How about Lync + sharing the browser? The interested (sharing + projector) parties join a Lync conversation. Then, any of the computers in the conversation can take over and share. The projector accepts the content and displays it on the screen. The desktop sharing is done over RDP protocol, so it should be pretty fast. You can read more here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator-help/quick-start-share-your-desktop-or-a-program-HA101832534.aspx